# Three.js Smooth Rotation with tween.js

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, smoothing, tween.js

I am trying to rotate a 2 face plane named slice_one  160 deg in smooth way.

I have tried this

```html
 new TWEEN.Tween(slice_one.rotation).to({ y: slice_one.rotation.y + Math.PI / 2 }, 1000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.EaseOut).start();
```

and the tween.update(); in animation function;

This method returns an error of three.min.js >> l is not a function <<

Is there another way to rotate in a smooth way the plane like THREE.Quaternion.setEuler ?

Here is my entire code

```html
<html>

<head>

    <title>My first Three.js app</title>

    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        container {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <img id="pic" />

    <canvas id="Canvas" style="display:none"></canvas>

    <button id="Folding"></button>

    <div id="container"></div>



    <script src="three.min.js"></script>



    <script src="Tween.js"></script>

    <script src="tween.min.js"></script>
    <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <script src="stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>



        var front = new Image();

        front.src = '1.jpg';



        var back = new Image();

        back.src = '1.jpg';



        var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        //Slice one front face

          function convert_f1() {


            canvas.width = front.width / 2;

            canvas.height = front.height;

            var sourceX = 0;

            var sourceY = 0;

            var sourceWidth = front.width / 2;

            var sourceHeight = front.height

            var destWidth = sourceWidth;

            var destHeight = sourceHeight;

            var destX = 0;

            var destY = 0;



            context.drawImage(front, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);

            dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

            console.log(dataURL);

            return dataURL;

          }

        //Slice one back face

          function convert_b1() {



              canvas.width = back.width / 2;

              canvas.height = back.height;

              var sourceX = back.width / 2;

              var sourceY = 0;

              var sourceWidth = back.width / 2;

              var sourceHeight = back.height

              var destWidth = sourceWidth;

              var destHeight = sourceHeight;

              var destX = 0;

              var destY = 0;



              context.drawImage(back, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);

              dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

              console.log(dataURL);

              return dataURL;

          }



          //Slice two front face

          function convert_f2() {



              canvas.width = front.width / 2;

              canvas.height = front.height;

              var sourceX = front.width / 2;

              var sourceY = 0;

              var sourceWidth = front.width / 2;

              var sourceHeight = front.height

              var destWidth = sourceWidth;

              var destHeight = sourceHeight;

              var destX = 0;

              var destY = 0;



              context.drawImage(front, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);

              dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

              console.log(dataURL);

              return dataURL;

          }

          //Slice two back face

          function convert_b2() {





              canvas.width = back.width / 2;

              canvas.height = back.height;

              var sourceX = 0;

              var sourceY = 0;

              var sourceWidth = back.width / 2;

              var sourceHeight = back.height

              var destWidth = sourceWidth;

              var destHeight = sourceHeight;

              var destX = 0;

              var destY = 0;



              context.drawImage(back, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);

              dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

              console.log(dataURL);

              return dataURL;

          }



        window.onload = function () {



           f1 = convert_f1();

           b1 = convert_b1();

           f2 = convert_f2();

           b2 = convert_b2();



           //document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + f1 + "')";

            var frontWidth = front.width/2;

            var frontHeight = front.height;



            var backWidth = back.width/2;

            var backHeight = back.height;



            var renderer, scene, camera, slice_one;

            var container, stats;



            init();

            animate();



            function init() {







                container = document.getElementById('container');

                // renderer

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

                renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);



                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2);

                container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);





                stats = new Stats();

                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';

                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

                container.appendChild(stats.domElement);



                // scene

                scene = new THREE.Scene();



                // camera

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);

                camera.position.z = frontHeight*2;

                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container);

                camera.lookAt(scene.position);



                // geometry

                var geometry1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(frontWidth, frontHeight, 1, 1);

                var geometry2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(backWidth, backHeight, 1, 1);

                geometry2.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.PI));





                var geometry3 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(frontWidth , frontHeight , 1, 1);

                var geometry4 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(backWidth , backHeight , 1, 1);

                geometry4.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.PI));



                // textures slice_one

                var texture_f1 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(f1);

                var texture_b1 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(b1);



                // textures slice_Two

                var texture_f2 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(f2);

                var texture_b2 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(b2);



                // material slice_one

                var material_f1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture_f1, color: 0xffffff, transparent: true });

                var material_b1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture_b1, color: 0xffffff, transparent: true });

                // material slice_two

                var material_f2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture_f2, color: 0xffffff, transparent: true });

                var material_b2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture_b2, color: 0xffffff, transparent: true });



                // slice_one

                slice_one = new THREE.Object3D();

                scene.add(slice_one);

                // positiion slice_one

                geometry1.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(-frontWidth / 2, 0, 0));

                geometry2.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(-frontWidth / 2, 0, 0));



                // mesh slice_one

                var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material_f1);

                slice_one.add(mesh1);

                var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material_b1);

                slice_one.add(mesh2);



                // slice_two

                slice_two = new THREE.Object3D();

                scene.add(slice_two);

                // position slice_two



                slice_two.position.x = frontWidth/2;

                slice_two.position.y = 0;

                slice_two.position.z = 0;

                // mesh slice_one

                var mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry3, material_f2);

                slice_two.add(mesh3);

                var mesh4 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry4, material_b2);

                slice_two.add(mesh4);





                //var grad = Math.PI / 2;

                //tween = new TWEEN.Tween(slice_one.rotation).to({ y: grad  }, 1000);
                //tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut);

                //tween.onComplete();

                //tween.start();+

                 

                //function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {



                //    event.preventDefault();

                //    new TWEEN.Tween(slice_one.rotation).to({ y: slice_one.rotation.y + Math.PI / 2 }, 1000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.EaseOut).start();

                //    //new TWEEN.Tween(plane.rotation).to({ z: plane.rotation.z + rad90 }, 1000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.EaseOut).start();


                //    console.log("click");

                //}



                //document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);


 
                 //new TWEEN.Tween(slice_one.rotation).to({ y: Math.PI / 2 }, 1000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.EaseOut).start();




            }

 

            function animate() {



                requestAnimationFrame(animate);

                slice_one.rotation.y += Math.PI / 60;



                 //TWEEN.update();

                stats.update();

                renderer.render(scene, camera);



            }



        }



    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are adding tween.js (aka tween.min.js) twice.. why?

Comment: Tween.js is the library that allows to make smooth rottation / translation .  In my case i need to make a plane rotate a certune dregree.

Comment: Yes I know. But why are you adding it twice?

    <script src="Tween.js"></script>
    <script src="tween.min.js"></script>